# Triggering a custom event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

Having this anywhere in the code :

```
$(".dates > tr > td > .notInTheMonth").bind('click', '.notInTheMonth', function() {
   ...
            
    $(this).one("updatedCalendar",function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })  
});
```

To trigger it, i've tried this :

```
$(".dates > tr > td > .notInTheMonth").trigger("updatedCalendar");
```

Why it will not work and how to make it work ?

## EDIT

Here is the html :

```
<body>
<div class="planner">
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="calendar-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <table class="itemsCalendar">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Lun
                    </th>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="dates">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">25</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">26</span>
                    </td>
                    ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="today">2</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span date="3-4-2016" class="">3</span>
                    </td>
                    ...
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    [...]
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span date="30-4-2016">30</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span date="31-4-2016">31</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">2</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">3</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">4</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="notInTheMonth">5</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is generated by javascript. It will output a planner, with the correct day according to the month and the years

Comment: You are only setting the bind, after clicking on the `.notInTheMonth`. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Don't take care of the date attr, it will be modified, i know it's not currently applied everywhere

Comment: Yes, it's what i want, i want to start an action in the element who have been clicked, setting it in other element is useless, and anyway, when the action is triggered once, it will be stopped

Comment: 1: you are using event delegation on a non-existing element. In other words, "notInTheMonth" has zero "notInTheMonth" children. Correct that behavior, then insert a console.log("hello"); inside the click handler to see if it's working.

Comment: I would also suggest you use .on instead of .bind If your jquery is >1.7